# How to replace null values with average values without using group by?

Tags: sql, hive

Assume there is a table `demoa` which contains following data:

```
date        a           b            c  
2017-05-22  1           6           10  
2017-05-23  2           7           11  
2017-05-24  3           8           12  
2017-05-25  4           9           null
2017-05-26  5           null        null
2017-05-27  null        null        null
```

I want to replace the `null` values with the average value of its corresponding column:

```
date        a           b            c
2017-05-22  1           6           10
2017-05-23  2           7           11
2017-05-24  3           8           12
2017-05-25  4           9           11
2017-05-26  5           7.5         11
2017-05-27  3           7.5         11
```

I tried `nvl` with `avg()`, but this requires `group by` of each column and cannot remove `null` values:

```
select 
    date,
    nvl(a,avg(a)),
    nvl(b,avg(b)),
    nvl(c,avg(c))
from damoa
group by date,a,b,c;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows functions -
`avg(...) over ()`

```
select  dt
       ,coalesce (a,avg(a) over ())  as a
       ,coalesce (b,avg(b) over ())  as b
       ,coalesce (c,avg(c) over ())  as c

from    demoa
```

---

```
+------------+-----+-----+------+
|     dt     |  a  |  b  |  c   |
+------------+-----+-----+------+
| 2017-05-22 | 1.0 | 6.0 | 10.0 |
| 2017-05-23 | 2.0 | 7.0 | 11.0 |
| 2017-05-24 | 3.0 | 8.0 | 12.0 |
| 2017-05-25 | 4.0 | 9.0 | 11.0 |
| 2017-05-26 | 5.0 | 7.5 | 11.0 |
| 2017-05-27 | 3.0 | 7.5 | 11.0 |
+------------+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks!  But I'm still confused why avg() requires 'group by' while avg() over() doesn't?

Comment: You'll have to study windows functions. I suggest you'll start with `row_number`.